# Env variables check during project build

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, dotenv

I am using create react app. I have an .env file. How can I check if there is a `REACT_APP_SMTH_VAR` variable in it during project build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a script somewhere in your project folder. For example in the root folder at same level than your `package.json`, called `checkenvs.js`, which does:

```
require('dotenv').config()
console.log('checking envs...')

if ('REACT_APP_SMTH_VAR' in process.env) {
  console.log('REACT_APP_SMTH_VAR is set')
} else {
  console.log('REACT_APP_SMTH_VAR not set')
}
```

Then change your build script in `package.json` to execute it before building your CRA app.

```
"scripts": {
  // other scripts
  "build": "node ./checkenvs.js && react-scripts build"
},
```

Those are the basics. From there you can put your script somewhere else, refactor the way you check your envs, log the output somewhere else, etc.

Comment: This doesn't find envvars configured in `.env.production` et al., which is honored by react-scripts build.